# Are elliptic pseudodifferential operators on manifolds with boundary Fredholm?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

On page 188 of "Topology and Analysis," Booss and Bleecker claim that the following theorem does **not** in general carry over to the case when the manifold $X$ has a nonempty boundary:

> Let $E$ and $F$ be vector bundles over $X$, $P\in\mathrm{Ell}_k(E,F)$, and $s,s-k\ge 0$. Then
>
> (a) The extension $P_s:W^s(E)\to W^{s-k}(F)$ is Fredholm with index independent of $s$.
>
> (b) $P^*$ is elliptic and $\operatorname{coker}P_s\cong\ker (P^*)_{s-k}$.
>
> (c) $\ker P_s=\ker P$.
>
> (d) $\operatorname{index}P=\operatorname{index}P_s$ depends only on the homotopy class of $\sigma(P)$ in $\mathrm{Iso}_{SX}^\infty(E,F)$.

For a different result, they specify that part (a) of that result carries over. That makes me think they are implying *no* part of this result carries over. But the only results we really need for this are Sobolev embedding and Rellich's theorem, both of which hold on manifolds with boundary. The only part of I'm not sure of is the independence of the index from $s$, because the argument given in the book is very vague. But one can circumvent it using regularity theory (i.e. prove (b) and (c) first), as is done in Gilkey, Hörmander, or Ward.

Comment: The example of the Laplacian shows that this is preposterous.

Comment: @MikeMiller They're not saying it can't ever hold, just that it doesn't hold in general.

Comment: My point is that the Laplacian is obviously *not* Fredholm. It has infinite-dimensional kernel by the solution of the Dirichlet problem.

Comment: @MikeMiller I'm not sure what you mean by the solution of the Dirichlet problem since a harmonic function vanishing on the boundary must be constant. But I guess one could restrict harmonic functions on the plane to the closed unit disk to see that the kernel can be infinite dimensional.

Comment: Without boundary conditions, there's no chance the operator will be Fredholm as can be already seen for the Laplacian. However, something like $L \colon W^{s}(E) \rightarrow W^{s - k}(F) \times W^{s - \frac{1}{2}}(E|_{\partial X})$ given by $\eta \mapsto (P\eta, \eta|_{\partial X})$ has the chance of being Fredholm. This is at least the case for domains with smooth boundary but in general there might be topological restrictions and subtleties.

Comment: @levap I'm wondering what goes wrong in the proof. It must be the existence of a parametrix, because parametrix + Rellich's theorem implies $P$ is Fredholm. But the authors say the parametrix theorem carries over, so I don't know.